# How to reference a randomly generated filename with flask

Tags: flask, random, filenames

I am creating a program that generates a chart, and then displays the chart on the webpage.  I want each chart generated to have a unique filename.  However, once that unique filename is generated, I don't know how to refer to it within the html file.

I use this to create a random filename starting with "chart" in the "images" folder.  This parts works fine.

```
basename = "images/chart"
suffix = str(uuid.uuid4())
filename = "_".join([basename, suffix])
plt.savefig(filename)
```

I then have this in the html file, but don't know how to modify to add the random suffix part of the name that was just generated.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = '/images/chart.png') }}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say without knowing more about the structure of your application, but one approach might be to change the template to something like

```
<img src="{{url}}">
```

and then calling it with

```
render_template('template.html', url=url_for('static', filename))
```

I'm no flask expert, but my instinct would be to avoid putting too much Python code — things like the `url_for` call — in the templates, because I do not want  to mix program logic with presentation.